# MySQL - UNION DISTINCT with extra column

Tags: mysql, distinct, union

I am trying to make a MySQL query for a "search" in one of my applications. This is what I currently have:

```
(SELECT id, title, 1 AS `order`
    FROM tasks
    WHERE title LIKE '%Task%Test%')
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT id, title, 2 AS `order`
    FROM tasks
    WHERE title LIKE '%Task%' AND title LIKE '%Test%')
ORDER BY `order` ASC;
```

The second query of the `UNION` kind of acts as a fallback for the first one, since the first query expects the words to be in the same order. (The amount of words is dynamic, depending on the search query.)

In the results, I want to show the results of the first query first, because those are more precise. To do this, I tried to add an extra column to the results: `order`.

My problem is that `DISTINCT` only works for rows that are entirely identical, which is not the case for my rows, because of the `orders` column.

**Example**

Table:

```
id    title
1     'Test Task'
2     'The Second Test Task'
3     'A Third Task For Testing'
4     'A Fourth Test'
```

Result:

```
id    title                         order
3     'A Third Task For Testing'    1
1     'Test Task'                   2
2     'The Second Test Task'        2
3     'A Third Task For Testing'    2
```

What I want:

```
id    title                         order
3     'A Third Task For Testing'    1
1     'Test Task'                   2
2     'The Second Test Task'        2
```

Anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why second conditions isnt  `WHERE title LIKE '%Test%Task%'` first condtion already got the one where Task is first. So the remaining if also have both mean Test is first

Comment: Because the amount of words to search for can change (it can also be `'%Test%Task%With%More%Words%'`, for example). Then I have to check for all possible orders, which has a big effect on the execution time. This approach should be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the same result from a single query without using a union:

```
SELECT
    id, title,
    CASE WHEN title LIKE '%Task%Test%' THEN 1
         WHEN title LIKE '%Task%' AND title LIKE '%Test%' THEN 2
         ELSE 3
    END AS label
FROM tasks
WHERE
    title LIKE '%Task%Test%' OR
    (title LIKE '%Task%' AND title LIKE '%Test%')
ORDER BY label;
```

### Demo

Comment: With the `WHERE` You dont need the `ELSE`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I know...I left it in there just as a marker.

Comment: This is probably faster than using the `UNION`?

Comment: Maybe, but still will be slower. This `LIKE` condition cant use index. If you want performance go with [TEXT SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: As a addition to  @JuanCarlosOropeza 's comment `LIKE 'a%'` can and will use a index if anny but `LIKE '%a%'` can't use a index

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by:

```
SELECT id, title, `order`
    FROM (
        (SELECT id, title, 1 as `order`
         FROM tasks
         WHERE title LIKE '%Task%Test%')
        UNION DISTINCT
        (SELECT id, title, 2 as `order`
         FROM tasks
         WHERE title LIKE '%Task%' AND title LIKE '%Test%')

    ) tb
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY `order` ASC;
```